# Korn script parameters

Tags: shell, ksh

I have came across a below code snippet and not sure exactly what's the purpose of **-?** in the while loop. I searched across multiple sites and forums for this parameter but couldn't get any exact answer.

Any inputs please, thank you.

```
while [[ $1 = -? ]]; do 
   case $1 in 
    -a) a1=alligator ;; 
    -b) a2=bear ;; 
    -c) a3=cougar ;; 
   esac 
   shift
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ksh, within double brackets, the `=` and `==` operators are for *pattern matching*: `[[ string = pattern ]]` [1]

These are shell pathname expansion patterns. `?` will match any single character.

So what you're testing for is if `$1` matches a hyphen followed by any single character. In other words, does the first positional parameter look like an option string.

[1] -- to perform string equality checking, your pattern either contains no special globbing characters, or such characters are quoted or escaped.

---

IMO, a more robust way to do option parsing is with the `getopts` builtin:

```
while getopts :abc opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) a1=alligator ;; 
        b) a2=bear ;; 
        c) a3=cougar ;; 
        :) print -u2 "error: missing required argument for -$OPTARG" ;;
        ?) print -u2 "unknown option: -$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir !! this helped me a lot and +1 for your detailed explanation and an alternate approach.